# retrieve key by providing value as a input in hashtable

Tags: java

I have input as a values. I need to retrieve key of that values in hashtable.

Please help to me sort out this. Appreciate your help.

Comment: There may be more than one key per value - you understand that, right?

Answer (score 3):

Basically that's not how a hash table works - you're expected to look up by key. You can iterate over all the entries and find the - potentially multiple - keys which map to the particular value, but it won't be fast.

Instead, you should consider using a [bidirectional map](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bidirectional_map) (bimap) such as the ones provided by [Guava](http://guava-libraries.googlecode.com), assuming your situation really calls for a single-key-to-single-value solution. (There are *lots* of options around collections in Guava; if you give us more information about your situation, we may be able to help more.)

Comment: [Commons Collections](http://commons.apache.org/collections/) has a similar collection, the [DualHashBidiMap](http://commons.apache.org/collections/api-release/org/apache/commons/collections/bidimap/DualHashBidiMap.html)

Comment: @Paul: Yes, but I try to stay away from non-generic collection classes these days :)

Comment: that's a good policy!  I'd forgotten that library isn't generified...so skip Commons Collections.

Comment: @JwalinShah: Given that you haven't actually told us much about what you're trying to achieve, it's hard to give a sample. Call `HashBiMap.create` to create a bimap, and then you can call `inverse()` to get the inverted key/value view.

Comment: Thanks Jon.. I appreciate your answer.

Answer (score 2):

What you are looking for is a BiMap data structure. [Google's guava](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git-history/v10.0.1/javadoc/index.html) provides an implementation of it. BidiMap interface in Commons Collections.